# Spring Tool Suite plugin for Eclipse deleted my WEB-INF file and I am getting a lot of errors Ask Question

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I had a web project. I installed the Spring Tool Suite for Eclipse as a plugin to shut down the Spring Boot application and now I am getting a lot of errors. Also, my webapp files are removed automatically. I didn't understand anything. My project was fine until the installation of STS plugin on the Eclipse.

Here is one of the error:

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/kadir/.p2/pool/plugins/univocity-parsers-2.5.9.jar (No such file or directory)
```

In addition to this, my application.properties file's symbol changed with Spring symbol

When I am trying 'spring-boot:run' from maven build:

```
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Then, I solve it by using the terminate button then compiled successfully but when I tried to enter the url, but it gives another error:

```
  javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [hello]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/hello] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

I found a question in StackOverflow. They had solved by deleting .m2 repository. I deleted it and now I am getting

```
  .p2/pool/plugins/univocity-parsers-2.5.9.jar (No such file or directory)
```

Can anyone know this issue?

Comment: that sounds like something got seriously wrong when installing the STS plugins. How did you install them? Via the Eclipse Marketplace? If so, which version? And what version of Eclipse do you use? The error starting with `.p2/pool` sounds like an Eclipse install issue, nothing related to the `.m2` local maven repo. And I have never heard of the `univocity-parser` jar, this is definitely not part of the STS plugins. Did you have additional plugins installed in your Eclipse previously?

Comment: As a second check, it is always worth to download a ready-to-use distribution of STS from spring.io/tools. It contains all you need for regular Spring Boot apps. Starting such a fresh install (version 4.2.2 at the moment) with an empty workspace would be worth a try, then importing your project as `Existing Maven Project` (in case you use Maven).

Comment: I downloaded it from Eclipse Marketplace. Sorry, I reinstalled Eclipse. So I couldn't remember the Eclipse version. Also, I deleted the STS plugin. Now I can run my project by adding the webapp/WEB-INF folder to my project manually. It is fine now. But I can only run it by using Right-click on the project -->Run As --> maven build.. --> Goals --> spring-boot:run. It is running. But I still can't stop it and I still don't know what the difference is between running it in this way and using the STS plugin. @Martin Lippert

Comment: No, I didn't install any plugin previously @MartinLippert

Comment: Also, can you suggest to me which spring boot version to choose? There are versions that 2.2.0 M3, 2.2.0 (SNAPSHOT),2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT),2.1.5, 1.5.21  @MartinLippert

Comment: I would recommend to use the latest release version of Spring Boot.

Comment: Can you try downloading a latest STS4 distribution from here: https://spring.io/tools - and import your project into a fresh workspace via "Import Existing Maven Project". If your boot project is configured as JAR type (using an embedded Tomcat), you should be able to start the project right from the boot dashboard. If you have the boot project configured as WAR packaged project, you can add a local Tomcat install to the "Servers" view and deploy and run your app from there.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I would recommend to open an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach a sample project to reproduce the issue, so that we can take a deeper look.

Comment: Can you tell me what the difference between plugin and STS program?  @MartinLippert

Comment: I am trying thank you

Comment: The Spring Tools 4 distribution for Eclipse is a ready-to-use Eclipse distribution with the Spring Tools 4 features pre-installed, together with a few other additional features that we think might be useful, and a special branding. It is based on the latest Eclipse release. You can achieve pretty much the same with downloading Eclipse and installing all these features into it, but you can avoid that hassle by using the ready-to-use distribution... :-)